# Run a batch script from Web browser

Tags: javascript, batch-file, browser, web-frontend

I would like to run a batch script from a web browser. I have a batch process that takes input folder as an input. Can I run it from web browser? I do not want to set up a server or anything. I just like to create a simple web interface with JavaScript and HTML. I am working with local files only.

Is it even possible? Are there any good alternative to this approach?

Comment: yes, but only in a convoluted way from your PC. it would be simpler to run a little node script that child processes the batch file...

Comment: Agree with @dandavis that a node script might be a good alternative. If you want a GUI, consider nw.js, or Electron as a couple of tools which will probably be better  than building for the browser, but make use of the same technologies.

Comment: Thanks @dandavis,barry-johnson. Can you please share some good (basic level) tutorials for that?

Comment: See [How to execute a Local File using HTML Application?](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/113678/How-to-execute-a-Local-File-using-HTML-Application).

Comment: Also you can use any web view from Qt or JavaFx etc, it's has more access possibilities from web app to os